# Searching for specific element in XML using Processing

Tags: xml, processing

Essentially I'm writing an XML document to store locations of shapes for a processing scene based on each frame they belong to.

Basically I'm having an issue determining if a specific frame already exists within the XML document.
The XML layout is set up like

```
<xmlDoc>
    <frame1>
        <unit1>
            <position x="1000" y="248"/>
        </unit1>
        ...
    </frame1>
    ...
</xmlDoc>
```

and the code that I assumed would work, but doesn't

```java
xml = loadXML("document.XML");

try
{
  XML children[] = xml.getChildren("Non_Existent_Frame");
  if(children == null)
  {
    print("child = null");
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  print(e)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might help if you told us what language you're doing this in.  It looks like C#?  If that's the case, I recommend LINQ to XML.

Comment: Also, you need to clarify "doesn't work".  Doesn't work how?  "Non_Existent_Frame" is not an element in your posted XML, BTW.

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry for the confusion. I'm using Processing, a java based program. I was hoping the above code would appear null, so I could then create the necessary frame within the XML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getChildren()` function returns an array containing any child elements with a particular tag. If that tag can't be found, then the array will be empty, not null. So you could just check for that:

```
XML children[] = xml.getChildren("Non_Existent_Frame");
if(children.length == 0)
{
```

Taking a step back, I wonder why you're using XML for this. Do you need to later read the file from something outside of Processing? If not (if you're just reading it back into the same program later), you might want to look into serialization instead.

Comment: That fixed it! I hadn't thought of a serialization implementation, I don't have too much experience with it but will read up on it shortly. Thank you for the suggestion and the help Kevin, it is much appreciated!